# How to iterate the multimap to write the key and values in the insertion order in a CSV file using java?

Tags: java, csv

```
Set keySet = myMultimap.keySet();
Iterator keyIterator = keySet.iterator();
while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
    List values = (List) myMultimap.get(key);
    System.out.println("keyname " + key);
    System.out.println("values " + values);
}
```

The above iteration produces the result in the following order

```
keyname id
values [1517049512, 102888752, 102888762, 1558590692, 1516493341, 1555855832, 1557068421, 1557460861, 1570321872, 1582701092]
keyname suspended
values [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

The expected result should be in the form

```
id          suspended      
1517049512  false
.....
1582701092  false
```

And to export it to CSV, I used the following code.

```
Set<String> keys = myMultimap.keySet();          
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/Csvfile/users.csv");
for (String keyname : keys) {
    writer.append(keyname);
    writer.append(","); 
}
writer.append("\n")        
for (String keyname : keys) {
    String result = myMultimap.values().toString();
    writer.append(result);
    writer.append("\n");
}
```

I'm using Guava multimap.

Can anyone help me to export the multimap key and values in to CSV file in the correct order?

If I use the above code, in my CSV file my key headers are not duplicating but my values are duplicating. The key-value pairs should come in the above order in the CSV file.

Comment: in your example you have 10 values for "id" and 8 values for "suspended" so you columns are not related and some rows might have null/empty values.. is that OK ?

Comment: s it can of empty values. that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that map is not sorted. When taking a key set - it's a set, unordered. Hence you would have to define some order.

This solution prints the data in order you expect. You just have to replace `System.out.print` with outputting to file instead (or collect it all into a string and do a single write at the end).

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Multimap<String, Object> myMultimap = newMultiMap();

        String[] keys = myMultimap.keySet().stream().sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
        List<?>[] values = stream(keys).map(myMultimap::get).toArray(List[]::new);
        int maxLength = stream(values).map(List::size).max(comparingInt(i -> i)).get();

        System.out.println(stream(keys).collect(joining("\t")));
        for (int line = 0; line < maxLength; line++) {
            for (List<?> value : values) {
                if (line < value.size()) {
                    System.out.print(value.get(line));
                } else {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static Multimap<String, Object> newMultiMap() {
        Multimap<String, Object> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

        myMultimap.put("id", 1517049512);
        myMultimap.put("id", 102888752);
        myMultimap.put("id", 102888762);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1558590692);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1516493341);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1555855832);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1557068421);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1557460861);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1570321872);
        myMultimap.put("id", 1582701092);

        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);
        myMultimap.put("suspended", false);

        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);
        myMultimap.put("verified", true);

        return myMultimap;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
id  suspended   verified
1517049512  false   true
102888752   false   true
102888762   false   true
1558590692  false   true
1516493341  false   true
1555855832  false   true
1557068421  false   true
1557460861  false   true
1570321872
1582701092
```

**EDIT:**

To write to file, just replace printing loop with a one which writes to file. You may want to change line separator.

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:/Csvfile/users.csv");) {
    writer.append(stream(keys).collect(joining(",")));
    writer.append("\r\n");
    for (int line = 0; line < maxLength; line++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            List<?> value = values[i];
            if (i != 0) {
                writer.append(",");
            }
            if (line < value.size()) {
                writer.append(String.valueOf(value.get(line)));
            }
        }
        writer.append("\r\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: The result is coming as expected but i need to export it into CSV. Can you suggest the possible ways to do the task ?

Comment: I got the result. It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set keySet = myMultimap.keySet();
Iterator keyIterator = keySet.iterator();

int maxLenght=-1;

// loop to get max number of rows
// and print Keys
while (keyIterator.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
    List values = (List) myMultimap.get( key );
    maxLenght = Math.Max(maxLenght , values.size());
    System.out.print(Key + "\t");
}

System.out.println();       // new line
keyIterator = keySet.iterator();// reset Iterator

// loop and print data row by row
for(int i=0 ; i<maxLenght ; i++){
    while (keyIterator.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String) keyIterator.next();
        List values = (List) myMultimap.get( key );
        if(values.size() < i){
            System.out.print(values.get(i) + "\t");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("\t\t");
        }
    }
}
```